# Ruby array changes by changing a 'copy' of one of its elements

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to confirm whether my understanding is correct of these six lines of code:

```
string="this is a sentence"
words=string.split
first_word=words[0]
first_word[0]=first_word[0].upcase
out=words.join(" ")
puts(out)
```

which prints "This is a sentence" (with the first letter capitalized).

It would appear that changing the "first_word" string, which is defined as the first element of the "words" array, also changes the original "words" array. Is this indeed Ruby's default behavior? Does it not make it more difficult to track where in the code changes to the array take place?

Comment: You're assigning a new string to the array element. An array isn't an immutable tuple. Why are you surprised that *assigning a new value* assigns a new value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need need to distinguish between a variable and an object. Your string is an object. `first_word` is a variable.

Look for example

```
a = "hello"
b = a
c = b
```

now all variables contain the *same* object, a string with the value "hello". We say they *reference* the object. No copy is made.

```
a[0] = 'H'
```

This changes the first character of the *object*, a string which now has the value "Hello". Both `b` and `c` contain the same, now changed object.

```
a = "different"
```

This assigns a new object to the variable `a`. `b` and `c` still hold the original object.

Is this Rubys default behaviour? yes. And it also works like this in many other programming languages.

Does it make it difficult to track changes? Sometimes.

If you takes an element from an array (like your `first_word`), you need to know:

If you change the object itself, no matter how you access it,
all variables will still hold your object, which just happened to be changed.

But if you replace the object in the array, like `words[0] = "That"`, then all your other variables will still hold the original object.

Comment: Thanks Meier, for the simple explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is caused by how ruby does pass-by-value and pass-by-reference.

This is probably one of the more confusing parts of Ruby. It is well accepted that Ruby is a pass-by-value, high level programming language. Unfortunately, this is slightly incorrect, and you have found yourself a perfect example. Ruby does pass-by-value, however, most values in ruby are references. When Ruby does an assignment of a simple datatypes, integers, floats, strings, it will create a new object. However, when assigning objects such as arrays and hashes, you are creating references.

```
original_hash = {name: "schylar"}
reference_hash = original_hash
reference_hash[:name] = "!schylar"
original_hash #=> "!schylar"

original_array = [1,2]
reference_array = original_array
reference_array[0] = 3
reference_array #=> [3,2]

original_fixnum = 1
new_object_fixnum = original_fixnum
new_object_fixnum = 2
original_fixnum #=> 1

original_string = "Schylar"
new_object_string = original_string
new_object_string = "!Schylar"
original_string #=> "Schylar'
```

If you find yourself needing to copy by value, you may re-think the design. A common way to pass-by-value complex datatypes is using the Marshal methods.

```
a = {name: "Schylar"}
b = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(a))
b[:name] = "!!!Schylar"
a #=> {:name => "Schylar"}
```

Comment: Do think it help to talk about marshalling to somebody who seem not yet understand the difference between variable and object?

Comment: The intention was not to talk about marshaling, rather to introduce an accepted way to copy a value.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is "pass by object reference" which in more practical terms is actually pointer represented by `object_id`, though this distinction is largely invisible.

Comment: Marshal/unmarshal is "an accepted way to copy a value" only insofar as you can do it if you have absolutely no other option. It's an awful kludge.